# What is a good algorithm for interpolating missing points of data given a set of X-Y coordinates?

Tags: algorithm, plot, graph, coordinates, interpolation

Here's a simple example; let's say you had an array with only two elements in it.  Each element is an X-Y coordinate.  The first element is (0, 0), and the next element is (3, 3).  I want to fill in the gaps so that the array is now

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

This is done by filling in all the integer value points in between the two elements already provided.  I feel like this should be really simple but for some reason I can't think of a good way to do it.  Is there a good algorithm for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take each neighbor and linearly interpolate. For example, if I had `[(0,0), (3,3)]`, I first figure out that the slope is 1. Then I see how much distance needs to be covered (3 units), and what distance each interval is (i.e. `(3/(num_interpolants+1))`). Then I multiply each distance by the slope and add to the y-value, while incrementing the x-value by the distance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make some notation first, assume that we want to interpolate linearly between point **A = (x<sub>a</sub>, y<sub>a</sub>)** and point **B = (x<sub>b</sub>, y<sub>b</sub>)**.

Also, let's assume that after the interpolation we want to have **n+1** points (with the original points **A** and **B** being the points with indices **0** and **n**, respectively).

Then, the following formulas give the coordinates of the **i**<sup>th</sup> point:

- x<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>a</sub> + (x<sub>b</sub> - x<sub>a</sub>) * i / n
- y<sub>i</sub> = y<sub>a</sub> + (y<sub>b</sub> - y<sub>a</sub>) * i / n

Comment: @user3047641 You're welcome! Thank you for the comment, I'm glad to know that the answer is helpful. :-) I'd also appreciate if you would up-vote and/or accept the answer!